# why the uniform norm in C[a,b] is invariant under linear transformation?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that the uniform norm in the space $C[a,b]$ is invariant under linear transformation $t=\alpha\tau+\beta$. About the context: The problem arises when I want to prove that this space can't be a Hilbert space.

I have a lot of doubts about how to show this, but I think that if I can prove that $C[a,b]$ and $C[c,d]$ are isometric for all values $a,b,c,d$ with $b>a$ and $d>c$, then the norm would also be invariant, because the norm is the distance between the vector $x$ and the vector $0$.

Without loss of generality, I already have a proof that $C[a,b]$ and $C[0,1]$ are isometric [available in the MHF][1], nevertheless I think that there is a step that is not completely justified. The outline of the proof is as follows:

1. Looking for an inyective function $F$ from $C[a,b]$ into $C[0,1]$, for example, you choose $F$ such that $F(u)=u((bt+(1-t)*a)$. Here you take a function $u$ which is an element of $C[a,b]$ and, using $F$ this $u$ becomes an element of $C[0,1]$.
2. Lets take  $u,w$ in $C[a,b]$ and $F$ allows to take  $F(u),F(w)$ in $C[0,1]$, now $d_{C[a,b]}(u,w)=\max_{t\in[a,b]} |u(t)-w(t)|=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|u(bt+(1-t)a)-u(bt+(1-t)a)|=d_{C[0,1]}(F(u),F(w))$

My doubt lies in that I do not know because they say that distances are the same. Is reasoning so obvious, or is there something extra to justify there?. Does the construction of $F$ contain all the justification?

The next step is to use this proof on $\tilde{x}(\tau)=1$ and $\tilde{y}(\tau)=1$, where $\tau\in{}[0,1]$ for to prove that this metric space can not be a Hilbert space, through the use of parallelogram equality.

Thanks very much.

PD: Excuse me, I'm not very good at writing in English.

Comment: Is your question about part 2?

Comment: What does MHF mean?

Answer (score 1):

You map $C[a,b]$ onto $C[c,d]$ by $Tf(x) = f(\tau(x))$ where $\tau$ is a homeomorphism of $[c,d]$ onto $[a,b]$.  An affine map $\tau$ will do.  Then it's obvious that the same values are taken by $f$ and $Tf$, and thus that the supremum norms are the same.